# python запись строки в файл N раз

Tags: python, файлы, циклы

Интересует вопрос: имеется две строки и tk.entry.

```
string1 = 'Сохранение переменной i инкремент'

string2 = 'статичная строка'
```

Получаю из текстбокса переменную = сколько раз надо получить в цикле запись строки и переменную для цикла for:

```
n = self.tb_level.get()
```

Запись в файл:

```
 o = open(file, 'w')
    
 o.write((string1+'\n' + string2+ '\n')) # ЭТО НАДО НАПИСАТЬ N РАЗ.
```

Что я хочу получить:

Допустим, что в переменной N мы ввели 5. В результате цикла получить и записать:

```
Сохранение переменной 1 инкремент
статичная строка

Сохранение переменной 2 инкремент
статичная строка

Сохранение переменной 3 инкремент
статичная строка

Сохранение переменной 4 инкремент
статичная строка

Сохранение переменной 5 инкремент
статичная строка
```

Собственно, проблемы две: записать N раз строки и получить для каждой строки i-й икремент.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для открытия файлов советую использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
with open("filename", "w") as f:
    f.write("some string")
```

С помощью нее вам не нужно беспокоиться о закрытии файла, он закроется автоматически после выполнения действий внутри конструкции.

Чтобы записать несколько строк нужно использовать цикл, например for:

```
for i in range(n):
    print(i)
```

Этот цикл при n = 3 выведет:

```
0
1
2
```

Соответственно, если вам нужно, чтобы инкремент начинался с 1, вы можете при записи в файл прибавить 1 к i

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло